# Installing numpy, cython, cpython for Python 2.7.12

Tags: python, numpy, cython, cpython

I have been trying to install numpy for Python 2.7.12 on a ubuntu 16.04 machine, but am not sure I am doing the right thing.

I issued the command

`python setup.py install`

and received the following error message:

```
ImportError: No module named Cython.Compiler.Main
```

So I have also been trying to install the cython package and received another error message:

```
/Cython-0.28.1/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:19:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I thought this problem required me to install cpython. Trying to install this resulted in the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sys, os, importlib.machinery, re, optparse
ImportError: No module named machinery
```

I am somewhat stumped about how to continue. Am I on the right path? Is there a different way I could try (the computer in question cannot connect to the internet)?

Comment: have you tried "pip install (name of the package)"? for example: pip install numpy

Comment: Do you have any reason you cannot connect to internet ? How did you copy setup.py to your target machine ?

Comment: @ymonad It's a pretty old computer with broken wifi. I have been copying files via usb stick.

Comment: You should emphasis in the question that you are trying to install in offline environment to get real answer. Maybe one method is creating anaconda environment in computer which is online, and copy it to  target machine, however I never tried it.

Comment: @ymonad Thanks, I might look into this.

Comment: Another option is that you can install  ubuntu 16.04 in online machine, or something like in docker, install all the packages which are required to install numpy and cython, and copy the content of the repository from it, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `pip` is install thanks to the command `which pip`, 
in my case :

```
$ which pip
/home/usr1/anaconda3/bin/pip
```

If `pip` is not install install it : [instruction  here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

then you should be able to use it such as :

```
pip install numpy
```

an alternative is to use : [`conda` install](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. Wouldn't this only work if I have an internet connection? The computer I am trying to set up does not have any.

Comment: @Ips yes of course, you won't be able to install any package without internet connexion. The alternative is to download from other computer with internet the full package at https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html (follow instruction)

Comment: That sounds great! I'll go with this. Many thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal use:

```
pip install numpy
```

If you get any error like 'permission denied', try:

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could I do this without an internet connection? I am trying to set up a computer that does not have any.

Comment: Alternatively you may install anaconda distribution which has many key packages.